# Please provide a mechanism for retrieving random questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, random

A lot of ideas I've had for Stack apps have been of the "question of the day" variety.  It would be nice if there was a way to retrieve one or more random questions.

```
/questions/random/
```

The `max` parameter could be used to determine how many results to return.  If no max is specified then only a single result should be returned.  All other parameters could apply to this, including `answers`, `body` and `sort`.

```
/questions/random/?max=10&body=true
```

I realize that I could simply have my app guess a random question ID or something, but most of these solutions will waste precious requests trying to find a positive result and will still only return one result at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this yourself pretty easily.

A random date range, with `todate` & `fromdate` on `/questions`, will work fine.  Basically, pick a random question (via `page`) from a random hour/day/week/month/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you call
the

`/questions`

method and just pick a random question from a random page?

Comment: Ah true, the paging would certainly replicate most of this functionality.  There's still a high degree of repeatability this way, requiring a few pages of results to be called if I wanted a more random set.